# Servlet 3.0 multipart-config doesn't work on max-file-size

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-3.0, multipartconfig

I'm using Spring-MVC to build restful service.
When serving a POST request using multipart-form, I want to limit the file size posted.
Normally the approach is as follow:

```
<web-app version="3.0"...

//...other code omitted

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/restful-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>500</max-file-size>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```

And my restful-context.xml is like:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
  </mvc:annotation-driven>

  <beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver"
    id="multipartResolver" />

  //...
</beans:beans>
```

Above is what [PRO SPRING 4](http://www.apress.com/9781430261513) tells me to do.
But the max-file-size does not take effect. I tried posting a very large file(near 1GB), and no exception was thrown.
Any one helps?

---

Later I removed the DispatcherServlet configuration from web.xml, instead I tried the annotaion style using @MultipartConfig, as follow(thanks to [@RE350](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206653/re350)):

```
@WebServlet(loadOnStartup = 1, name = "restful", urlPatterns = { "/restful/*" }, initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "contextConfigLocation", value = "/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/restful-context.xml") })
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 500)
public class MyDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {}
```

And it workded!!!
So why the web.xml way does not work? Waiting for your answer.

Comment: Where did you host the app, may be it is not a Servlet 3+ container?

Comment: @BijuKunjummen I'm using STS built-in Pivotal tc Server, which should be using an embedded tomcat 8.0.9

Answer (score 2):

I think max-file-size takes values as bytes,you will have to multiply 500 by 1024 * 1024 like below.

```
     <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>524288000</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>524288000</max-request-size>
    </multipart-config>
```

More over if you are using Spring MVC,you could have used `@MultiPartConfig` annotation on your Spring service like below.

```
@MultipartConfig(location="/tmp", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024, 
    maxFileSize=1024*1024*5, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5)
```

Answer (score 0):

your need both max-file-size and max-request-size and file-size-threshold

```
<multipart-config>
    <max-file-size>500</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>700</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```